# Is this code actually thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a question regarding the following code segment which I found on Microsoft's C# tutorial web page. In the code they provide a demo of tasks. In the event handler they create a task which updates an unprotected collection.

Is this code thread-safe? In my opinion it's not. What is the best way to make this code thread-safe?

```
private ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
private void btnCreateStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Student newStudent = new Student();
    newStudent.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    newStudent.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
    newStudent.City = txtCity.Text;
    ClearForm();
    Task task1 = new Task(() => AddToCollection(newStudent));
    task1.Start();
    ClearForm();
}

private void AddToCollection(Student student)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    students.Add(student);
    int count = students.Count;
    MessageBox.Show("Student created successfully.  Collection contains " + count.ToString() + " Student(s).");
}
```

I disagree with the following statement

```
students.Add(student);
```

I think it should be protected by a lock.

Comment: You mean Thread _safe_?

Comment: at what MSDN page did you this? What in particular are you wondering is thread safe? The Add call? I'm actually not sure that this code would function correctly, since you are calling MessageBox.Show in a task. Those should run on the UI thread.

Comment: no it works fine with regard the  MessageBox.Show  i compiled it and it is working . My concern with regard  students.Add(student);

Comment: I found a more exctended code [here](http://pastebin.com/iDtrmUvV) and is not MSDN

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` it is leftover from .NET 1.1 days before generics exited. You should be using `List<Student>` instead.

Comment: If you read microsoft's blurb on the `Array List` Class.
`Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
An ArrayList can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. To guarantee the thread safety of the ArrayList, all operations must be done through the wrapper returned by the Synchronized method.`

Comment: The MessageBox.Show() is a thread-safe call (because it's static). The ArrayList.Add() is not.

Comment: _should be protected by a lock_ is formally the answer, but not the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this code actually thread-safe?

No, it's not.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) the `ArrayList` instance doesn't support concurrent modification, unless it's returned by the `Synchronized` method and it's not the case here.

Although it may not be obvious, the concurrent modification can happen in your example. The `Task` is queued to the `ThreadPool` and it will be run by some thread from this pool. If a user double clicks `btnCreateStudent` two tasks will be created, and since `Thread.Sleep` is not very precise and, anyway, the tasks don't have to be executed immediately (for example the ThreadPool queue may be full), thus two tasks, although scheduled at different times, may be executed at the same time.

> What is the best way to make this code thread-safe?

It depends on what you mean by "the best".

The first solution would be to create the `ArrayList` with the [`Synchronized`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ec5w0c2(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
private ArrayList students = ArrayList.Synchronized(new ArrayList());
```

But you will still have to use a lock for enumerating this list.

> Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. Even when a collection is synchronized, other threads can
>   still modify the collection, which causes the enumerator to throw an
>   exception. To guarantee thread safety during enumeration, you can
>   either lock the collection during the entire enumeration or catch the
>   exceptions resulting from changes made by other threads.

The other solution would be to use the [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and add locks wherever the collection is accessed. The `List<T>` is superior to the `ArrayList` because it contains the elements type, so you don't have to cast them on read, or you won't accidentally add an incompatible type to the collection.

If you don't care about the order of items, then you should use the [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx), which doesn't require any locking.

Answer (score 1):

"*Thread safety*" depends highly on what you do outside of the seperate thread.
If you don't touch `students` at all outside of your task during the runtime of the task, your code is thread safe.

If you use `students` outside during the task's lifetime you should synchronize the access.
You can do this with a `lock` or [other synchronization methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can of course also use some of the [concurrent collections.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I invoke the Task periodically . Each mouse click will create a separate Tread . What will lead to many competing threads

Comment: @DavidYachnis Then you need a synchronization.